# How to use Internet connection of a remote server in the local machine?

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, remote-access

Is it possible to use internet connection of a server in our local computer as my local internet connection is too slow and the internet connection on my remote machine is too fast. Is there any possible way to do that over ssh or something?

Answer (score 1):

If the limitation is your local PC's bandwidth, then browsing over an SSH Tunnel will not increase your local connection speed.  The limit will still exist.

If, however you're going to use the remote machine to download, and save there (not on your local machine), then there are definite speed benefits.

This can be complicated though, and depends entirely on what you want to achieve.

I'd suggest reading the official [OpenSSH/PortForwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding) document.

I've already set the link to go directly to the "Local Port Forwarding" section.  It seems this is most likely what you're looking for.

Comment: But how can I get the files downloaded to the remote server to my local machine?

Comment: Well, I have a very low bandwidth problem, so what I do, is download the files on a remote machine, then use an application called [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) to replicate the data to my local machine overnight.  Once it gets here, I copy it off to my hard drive, and delete the local version.  It syncs back up to the remote server and automatically deletes it there.  Rinse and repeat :)

Comment: @AshishKulkarni - Doing it that way would take *longer* than just downloading it to your local machine...

Comment: Yes, but more convenient when you have 5 machines using the connection during the day.  Overnight, the bandwidth is freed up, and sync is faster.  Also, this is getting off topic.  The answer to your question is basically, no.  It will not help you fix your local connection.

Comment: Allright! Thank you. But is there any way to transfer files through torrent or something?

Comment: You could, but the bandwidth issues remain.  Using a remote server will not speed up your local connection.  Speeding up the local connection would be the only method of increasing the speed of transfer between you and the remote machine.  Remember, Torrents are at the mercy of your local connection as well.  If your local connection is slow, then all incoming data through that connection will be slow.