# Can I use the internet of a remote server on my local machine?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, vpn

my question is similar to this:

[How to use Internet connection of a remote server in the local machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848180/how-to-use-internet-connection-of-a-remote-server-in-the-local-machine)

However I found no useful answer. I have access to a remote server via a VPN connection. In the server I can access to internet. The server is Ubuntu 16 and I am in sudoers and can install required tools.
I want to have access to internet via this server. One benefit is that the server is inside my country and the data transfer between them is cheaper...

Anyway, if it's possible, please guide me what should I do in my local machine and remote server

This is what I tried:

```
sudo sshpass -p xxxx ssh -N -f -L localhost:8001:localhost:80 yyyy@172.16.143.8
```

It runs with no error, but when I browse localhost:8001, it gives connection error `Unable to connect`...

Comment: @user535733 The question doesn't say much about his access on the remote server, I added that I have root access on both systems, so I can install or run any program if it's needed.... So, my expected answer could be like `run that on remote`... `do tunnel forwarding`....

Comment: @user535733 I added my efforts too

Comment: It can be easier than that. Check your routing table (`route`). Make your primary Gateway the server instead of your local router.

Comment: You can use ssh / socks proxy. No extra tools will be needed besides an ssh server and client. Or you can install and configure a VPN server, like WireGuard.

Answer (score 0):

I setup squid proxy server on the remote server:

https://phoenixnap.com/kb/setup-install-squid-proxy-server-ubuntu

Then I set the proxy server of my local machine to the ip of remote server and the port `3128`, and now it's working